# starting a job remotely with bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash script on a remote machine, and I'd like to return immediately after running the script in the background of the remote machine. For instance:

```
$ echo foo.txt
sleep 2000 &
```

then when I tried to do:

```
$ ssh x.x.x.x 'bash -s' < foo.txt
```

the command never returns. Is there a way to make it return while `sleep` runs in the background on the remote machine?

Comment: put the ssh command in the background as well.

Answer (score 1):

May by;

```
echo foo.txt
sleep 2000 >&- 2>&- <&- &
```

- `>&-` means close stdout.
- `2>&-` means close stderr.
- `<&-` means close stdin.
- `&` means run in the background